# JavaScript redirect it isn't working on server, but on localhost?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I've build a little website : http://rolandgroza.com/projects/tcsg/ , but it seems to have a problem that I have not encountered before moving the files to the server. I usually test on localhost before deploying on server, so I only saw the problem after I did.

You can see my JavaScript script in the source code, but I'm placing it here too:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var header  =   $('body').find('header');
var footer  =   $('body').find('footer');
var badge   =   $('body').find('.badge-wrapper');

var logo_red = $(header).find('.logo a');

var navigation = {
    home:       $('body').find('.home'),
    about:      $('body').find('.about'),
    services:   $('body').find('.services'),
    contact:    $('body').find('.contact')
}

var container = {
    home:       $('body').find('.content-home-wrapper'),
    about:      $('body').find('.content-about-wrapper'),
    services:   $('body').find('.content-services-wrapper'),
    contact:    $('body').find('.content-contact-wrapper')
}

var home = {
    form:       $(container.home).find('.form-wrapper'),
    galleries:  $(container.home).find('.galleries-wrapper')
}

var about = {
    notepad:    $(container.about).find('.notepad-wrapper')
}

var services = {
    minimum:    $(container.services).find('.minimum-package'),
    medium:     $(container.services).find('.medium-package'),
    featured:   $(container.services).find('.featured-package')
}

var contact = {
    notepad:    $(container.contact).find('.notepad-wrapper')
}

var position = function (obj) {
    return {
        'top': (($(window).height() - $(obj).outerHeight()) / 2) + 'px',
        'left': (($(window).width() - $(obj).outerWidth()) / 2) + 'px'
    }
}

var current_page = function() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var current_page = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    return current_page;
}

var curr_pag = current_page();

switch (curr_pag) {
    case 'index.php':
        $(navigation.home).addClass('selected');
        break;
    case 'about.php':
        $(navigation.about).addClass('selected');
        break;
    case 'services.php':
        $(navigation.services).addClass('selected');            
        break;
    case 'contact.php':
        $(navigation.contact).addClass('selected');
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

$(logo_red).on('click', function() {
    var page = current_page();
    switch (page) {
        case 'index.php':
            $(home.form).removeClass('animated flipInX');
            $(home.galleries).removeClass('animated flipInX');
            $(home.form).addClass('animated fadeOutLeftBig');
            $(home.galleries).addClass('animated fadeOutRightBig');
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.href = 'index.php';
            }, 2000);
            break;
        case 'about.php':
            $(about.notepad).removeClass('animated flipInX');
            $(about.notepad).addClass('animated flipOutX');
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.href = 'index.php';
            }, 2000);
            break;
        case 'services.php':
            $(services.minimum).removeClass('animated flipInY');
            $(services.medium).removeClass('animated flipInY');
            $(services.featured).removeClass('animated flipInY');
            $(services.minimum).addClass('animated fadeOutLeftBig');
            $(services.medium).addClass('animated fadeOutDownBig');
            $(services.featured).addClass('animated fadeOutRightBig');
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.href = 'index.php';
            }, 2000);
            break;
        case 'contact.php':
            $(contact.notepad).removeClass('animated flipInX');
            $(contact.notepad).addClass('animated flipOutX');
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.href = 'index.php';
            }, 2000);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
})

for(var key in navigation) {
   var object = navigation[key];
   $(object).on('click', function(e){
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).addClass('animated hinge');
        var page = current_page();
        switch (page) {
            case 'index.php':
                $(home.form).removeClass('animated flipInX');
                $(home.galleries).removeClass('animated flipInX');
                $(home.form).addClass('animated fadeOutLeftBig');
                $(home.galleries).addClass('animated fadeOutRightBig');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.href = link;
                }, 2000);
                break;
            case 'about.php':
                $(about.notepad).removeClass('animated flipInX');
                $(about.notepad).addClass('animated flipOutX');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.href = link;
                }, 2000);
                break;
            case 'services.php':
                $(services.minimum).removeClass('animated flipInY');
                $(services.medium).removeClass('animated flipInY');
                $(services.featured).removeClass('animated flipInY');
                $(services.minimum).addClass('animated fadeOutLeftBig');
                $(services.medium).addClass('animated fadeOutDownBig');
                $(services.featured).addClass('animated fadeOutRightBig');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.href = link;
                }, 2000);
                break;
            case 'contact.php':
                $(contact.notepad).removeClass('animated flipInX');
                $(contact.notepad).addClass('animated flipOutX');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.href = link;
                }, 2000);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    })
}

$(badge).hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated swing');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('animated swing');
    }
);

setTimeout(function(){
    $(header).addClass('animated fadeInDown');
    $(footer).addClass('animated fadeInUp');
    $(badge).addClass('animated swing');
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){
    $(home.form).addClass('animated flipInX');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(home.galleries).addClass('animated flipInX');
    }, 500);
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function(){
    $(about.notepad).addClass('animated flipInX');
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function(){
    $(services.minimum).addClass('animated flipInY');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(services.medium).addClass('animated flipInY');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(services.featured).addClass('animated flipInY');
        }, 500);
    }, 500);
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function(){
    $(contact.notepad).addClass('animated flipInX');
}, 2000);

for(var key in container) {
   var object = container[key];
   var css = position(object);
   $(object).css(css);
}

$('select').dropkick();

});
```

The problem is that when clicking one of the menu links there should be some animations happening and then redirected to a the link you clicked on, with `window.location.href` , but it doesn't work, almost anything.

I cannot tell what is the problem so I'm hoping someone can, because on XAMPP localhost works fine.

Comment: are you sure the paths to your css files are correct? I dont see them when opening the url in Firefox.

Comment: What do css files have to do with the `location.href` ? I'm working with LESS, but the CSS is there I assure you since everything seems to look OK, in Chrome at least, I haven't tested on other browsers yet.

Comment: I wasn't answering the question, Just wondering where the css was. After a refresh I see graphics. (looks nice). The page is loading slowly and Firefox is throwing an error about the script being busy.

Comment: @Roger - I see, well I really don't know what's happening :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in that your asking the current page, and on your home page when the index.php isn't in the url your missing something and your switch cases arn't working. Add to your switch function in the navigation a case for having no page or page == '' that way it will know what to do. Hope that helps!

Comment: OK, let me try, but why is this happening only on the server but not on localhost ?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, I forgot about having no page address when requesting the root directory :) I encountered this problem before and I forgot :) Thank you for pointing it @mlantz .

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with htaccess? I've had problems with that before myself.

Comment: No, it was because of what you specified, the switch case stopped when it encountered that case.